# NullPointerException in ControlsFX Notification

Tags: javafx, nullpointerexception, controlsfx

I want to show notifications to the user in my JavaFX application and chose the ControlsFX library for that purpose. However whenever I create a warning via: `Notifications.create().showWarning();`, I get the following Exception:

```
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.controlsfx.controls/org.controlsfx.control.Notifications$NotificationPopupHandler.getScreenBounds(Notifications.java:364)
    at org.controlsfx.controls/org.controlsfx.control.Notifications$NotificationPopupHandler.show(Notifications.java:343)
    at org.controlsfx.controls/org.controlsfx.control.Notifications.show(Notifications.java:305)
    at org.controlsfx.controls/org.controlsfx.control.Notifications.showWarning(Notifications.java:271)
```

This is called when my whole application is set up and visible.

Could this be a version mismatch? I use JavaFX 12 but ControlsFX only has a version 11.

This is an abbreviated version of my `pom.xml`:

```
<project xmlns="[...]">
    [...]
    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.release>12</maven.compiler.release>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>
    <build>

        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <release>${maven.compiler.release}</release>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
                <artifactId>javafx-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>0.0.3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <mainClass>eu.snik.tag.gui.Main</mainClass>
                </configuration>
            [...]
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
              [...]
    <dependencies>
    [...]       
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-controls</artifactId>
            <version>12.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-fxml</artifactId>
            <version>12.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-web</artifactId>
            <version>12.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.controlsfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>controlsfx</artifactId>
            <version>11.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a bug that is now fixed, see https://github.com/controlsfx/controlsfx/issues/1140

Unfortunately the bugfix is not included in the current release (or any release candidate: According to the version history it was fixed April 30th, 2019 but the last release was on the 19th of the same month).

Note that the code before the check for `null` preventing the NPE was added iterated through the window list returned by `Window.getWindows()` looking for a window that is focused. `null` is used, if no such window is found. With the current code the primary screen is used, to determine the position of the notification, if no focused window is found.

Comment: Thanks! I tried to go back to RC2 but it had a different bug, but I worked around the problem by explicitly specifying the window that the notification should use.